# Mysql create procedure (create statement) inside qt

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I need a way to auto create a procedure inside my qt code. My seniors said that currently in our version of qt lib (4.7.3) it is not possible to use query.exec function. Maybe i can use qprocess? Please give me some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/16287-Cannot-create-MySQL-stored-procedure-views-from-Qt
This answer my question.
Do not use mysql delimiters (such as $$).
And separate the execution of drop and create.

```
QSqlQuery query;
QString command= "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS PROC_X";
query.exec(command);

command = "CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_X";//(Just put your own statement there)
query.exec(command);
```